# The best way to implement massively parallel application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm working on a network-bound application, which is supposed to have a lot (hundreds, may be thousands) of parallel processes.

I'm looking for the best way to implement it.

When I tried setting

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
```

and than creating 1000 threads and making those do stuff in parallel, application's execution became really jumpy.

I've heard somewhere that `delegate.BeginInvoke` is somehow better that `new Thread(...)`, so I've tried it, and than opened the app in debugger, and what I've seen are parallel threads.

If I have to create lots and lots of threads, what is the best way to ensure that the application is going to run smoothly?

Comment: do you really need **threads** or wouldnt it be better to use async? Esp. the new async/await features in FW 4.5? And if you fire out 1.000 threads they will all compete for cores which means lot of context switching overhead and so on.

Comment: Having 1,000 threads is probably only a good idea on a super computer (or at least a cluster of several dozen computers, which wouldn't quite qualify as a super computer, but still).  A single PC will be crushed from the weight of 1,000 threads (if it doesn't crash before you've created that many to begin with).

Comment: Also thread management with that many threads will ruin performance. You also won't have any true parallelism. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720724(v=vs.71).aspx for more.

Comment: @Servy I'm working on a 6 dual core (12 soft cores) x5675 processor, and it still sucks with 1000 threads. I think, it's something about the operating system not being able to handle this number of threads per app

Comment: @ArsenZahray Yep.  If you had a dozen or so computers with those specs then it would probably be able to manage fine (with 1000 total threads, not per machine), or likewise, if you had around 1/12th as many threads it would be able to manage well enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the new `await / async` pattern in C# 5 / .NET 4.5?

I haven't got sources to hand about how this operates under the hood, but one of the most common use-cases of this new feature is waiting for IO bound stuff.

---

Threads are **not** lightweight objects. They are expensive to create and context switch to/from; hence the reason for the Thread Pool (pre-created and recycled). Most common solutions that involve networking or other IO ports utilise lower-level IO Completion Ports (there is a managed library [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10280/Managed-I-O-Completion-Ports-IOCP)) to "wait" on a port, but where the thread can continue executing as normal.

`BeginInvoke` will utilise a Thread Pool thread, so it will be better than creating your own ***only*** if a thread is available. This approach, if used too heavily, can immediately result in thread starvation.

Setting such a high thread pool count is not going to work in the long run as threads are too heavy for what it appears you want to do.

---

Axum, a former Microsoft Research language, used to achieve massive parallelism that would have been suitable for this task. It operated similarly to Stackless Python or Erlang. Lots of concepts from Axum made their way into the parallelism drive into C# 5 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: await and async are just operators to interact with the task parallels library, it could be a pretty good option, google "Task.Run" and refer to the TPL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: @SalvadorSarpi Thanks for the link. If only I had the time to dive into all this new stuff! :-)

Comment: Is `await/async` any different that `delegate.BeginInvoke`? I always though that it was only a more convenient way to do the same

Comment: @ArsenZahray `async/await` has *nothing* to do with starting new threads.  You need to use some other existing mechanism to actually start and schedule the task.  All `async/await` does is help make it easier to schedule continuations from those task so that rather than having your code spread out between many different callback methods it can be in a single method, written mostly as if the code ran sequentially.  It's a **great** feature, but it's a common misconception that it in any way results in actually takes synchronous code and makes it asynchronous.  (It kinda does the opposite.)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads will only affect how many threads the thread pool has, and it won't make a difference regarding threads you create yourself with new Thread().

Go async (model, not keyword) as suggested by many.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the advice mentioned in the other answers and comments. As fsimonazzi says, creating new threads directly has nothing to do with the ThreadPool. For a quick test lower the max worker and completionPort threads and use the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) method. The ThreadPool will decide what your system can handle, queue your tasks and resuse threads whenever it can.

If your tasks are not compute-bound then you should also utilize asynchronous I/O. You do not your worker threads to wait for I/O completion. You need those worker threads to return to the pool as quickly as possible and not block on I/O requests.